Layout completely different in firefox and chromium based browsers
I am working on a website for a school project and I noticed that the layout I created and tested in chromium based browsers is completely broken when view in firefox.
The first issue seems to be with the a#logo-container element not setting its size according to its child element.
The second issue is that even tho #user-menu is set to "display: none;" it still takes up space in the layout and pushes everything to the left.
The project itself is writen in svelte but I extracted the weird behaving bits into a codepen:
https://codepen.io/0324bence/pen/MYgeZwj
HTML:
<div style="display: contents">
  <div id="window-container" on:click="{closeMenu}">
    <div id="header">
      <a href="/" id="logo-container">
        <div class="container" style="aspect-ratio: 290 / 136">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 290 136" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            /*SVG code in codepen*/
          </svg>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div id="center-container">
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Keresés..." />
          <button type="submit">
            <div class="container" style="aspect-ratio: 32 / 32">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                /*SVG code in codepen*/
              </svg>
            </div>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="right-container">
        <div class="container" style="aspect-ratio: 100 / 90">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 100 90" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            /*SVG code in codepen*/
          </svg>
        </div>

        <button id="user-button">
          <div class="container" style="aspect-ratio: 100 / 100">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/YsYybca.png" alt="User profile icon" />
          </div>
        </button>
        <div id="user-menu" class="hidden">
          <a href="/profile" class="menu-item">Profil</a>
          <a href="/advert/create" class="menu-item">Új hirdetés</a>
          <a href="/auth/logout" class="menu-item" data-sveltekit-reload>Kijelentkezés</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <slot />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

SCSS:
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap";
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap";

$color-white: #ffffff;
$color-black: #000000;
$color-red: #ca2918;
$color-light-blue: #95c2e4;
$color-blue: #2b84c9;
$color-dark-blue: #164265;

//global
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: $color-white;
  color: $color-black;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
  &:visited {
    color: hsl(240, 100%, 60%);
  }
  &:hover {
    color: hsl(240, 100%, 70%);
  }
}

//svg stuff
.light-blue {
  fill: #95c2e4;
}

.dark-blue {
  fill: #164265;
}

.black {
  fill: #000000;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}

//main
#window-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 7rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: $color-blue;
  position: relative;

  #logo-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
  }

  #center-container {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;

    form {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 0.5rem;
      padding: 0.5rem;
    }

    input {
      flex: 1;
    }

    input,
    button {
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-radius: 15px;
      border: 1px solid $color-dark-blue;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      outline: none;
    }

    button {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 2.5rem;
      width: 2.5rem;
    }
  }

  #right-container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0.7rem;

    button {
      background: none;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #user-menu {
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 2px;
      align-items: stretch;
      z-index: -1;
      top: 100%;
      right: 0;
      background-color: $color-dark-blue;
      border: 1px solid $color-dark-blue;
      width: 20rem;
      pointer-events: all;
      transition: transform 0.3s;
      // transform: translateY(0%);
      visibility: visible;

      &.hidden {
        // transform: translateY(-100%);
        pointer-events: none;
        display: none;
        // visibility: hidden;
      }

      .menu-item {
        background-color: $color-white;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        color: $color-black;
        font-size: 1.2rem;

        text-decoration: none;

        cursor: pointer;

        &:hover {
          background-color: darken($color-white, 10%);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Typescript
let menuState = false;

const windowContainer = document.getElementById("window-container")!;

const userButton = document.getElementById("user-button")!;

const userMenu = document.getElementById("user-menu")!;

userButton.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    userMenu.classList.toggle("hidden");
});

windowContainer.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (menuState) userMenu.classList.add("hidden");
});

Here are images of my exact problem:
The layout in chromium based browsers (as it is intended):

The layout in firefox (broken):

Any help is appreciated!
Edit 1:
Defining the correct aspect-ration on a#logo-container fixes the issue of the element not expanding correctly.

Firefox uses a different browser engine than Chromium based browser, so if you only check with the latter, chances are it won't work perfect with the former. Sorry, for stating the obvious. You could try to better follow the HTML5 standards. For instance, don't put an element that's naturally a "block" inside an element that is naturally an "inline" element. So not: a > div > svg but div > a > svg. That would solve the logo problem.

Why not making an answer from that ?

The issue arises because a#logo-container doesn't inherit the size of its child div.container that uses aspect-ratio. In Firefox, aspect-ratio alone doesn't propagate its calculated size up the DOM hierarchy.
To fix this, you should explicitly define the size for a#logo-container. You can do so by applying the same aspect-ratio property and ensuring that the parent has appropriate width or height to calculate from. For example:
<a href="/" id="logo-container" style="aspect-ratio: 290 / 136; display: block;">
  <div class="container" style="aspect-ratio: 290 / 136">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 290 136" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <!-- SVG code -->
    </svg>
  </div>
</a>

Adding display: block; ensures that the <a> element behaves as a block-level element, which is necessary for the aspect-ratio to apply correctly. Without this, inline elements like <a> won't respect the aspect-ratio.

#logo-container already has "display: block;" and adding an aspect ration does fix the issue of the logo, however the issue with the pofile icon on the right still persists
